# != query fail how do you use both = and != in the same where statement

Tags: mysql

This query works:

```
SELECT stock_number 
FROM t2d_vehicles
WHERE stock_number = '02929A'
AND dealer_id = 130128
```

This one does not:

```
SELECT stock_number 
FROM t2d_vehicles 
WHERE stock_number = '02929A' 
AND dealer_id = 130128 
AND feed_id != 9
```

Can I not combine != with an = in a WHERE?

Here is a simple little bit of the table:

```
"stock_number","dealer_id","feed_id"
"02929A",130128,9
"02929A",130128,10
```

Comment: It should work and should result no records

Comment: What error are you receiving? Typically you would use `<>` for not equal.

Comment: you need to be more specific; there's nothing wrong with your query syntax so you need to tell us what you mean by "not working".

Comment: There was an error in the sample data. Both rows should show the same dealer ID.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL `!=` should work fine, but actually the prefered syntax in standard SQL is `<>`. According to the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal) the two operators should do the same thing.

Comment: The query returns no result, it should return one row.

Comment: @chuck: If it *does* return zero rows, it's almost certainly because it *should* return zero rows. The problem is most likely that you *think* it should return one row when in fact it shouldn't. The solution is to **stop thinking that**. Instead to try to understand *why* it returns zero rows. Do some experiments. The reason is almost certainly something *trivial and obvious* but you've overlooked it because you think the mistake is in MySQL when actually the mistake is either in your head or in the data you've put into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using NOT?

SELECT stock_number FROM t2d_vehicles WHERE stock_number = '02929A' AND dealer_id = 130128 AND (NOT feed_id = 9)

Answer (score 0):

If `feed_id` is `NULL`, `feed_id != 9` will be `true`.

Try this:

```
...
AND (feed_id != 9 OR feed_id IS NULL)
```

In SQL, `NULL` is neither equal, nor not equal, to amy specific value.